# think it fair criticism (grammar question, can't understand)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

*In the past, SQL has been criticized for having an inappropriate name. Structured Query Language lacks a proper structure, does more than just queries, and only barely qualifies as a programming language. You might **think it fair criticism** then, but let me make three comments...*

I can't grammatically understand ***think it fair criticism***. Is ***it*** the object of ***think*** and ***fair criticism*** an adverbial phrase or something like that? Is this grammatically similar to the construction ***deem it necessary***? Please, break it down for me, maybe, with examples.

Comment: It comes from _think it to be fair criticism_, with _to be_-deletion. Note that the passive works very nicely: _It was thought to be fair criticism,_ though _to be_-deletion is not so good with the passive: _??It was thought fair criticism._ _Consider_ works better than _think_ here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might think it fair criticism

What structure is "think it fair criticism"?

After a lot of verbs you can add an object that consists of an accusative (direct object) and a to-infinitive.
A special group of these verbs could be classified as "verbs expressing opinion" such as

believe, consider, declare, find, hold, judge, know, recognize, suppose, take (in the sense of to suppose), think, understand

In normal language you add a that-clause: I think (that) the measures of the government are appropriate.
In written language, in a more elevated style, you often find the verb construction verb accusative to-infinitive:

- I think the measures of the government to be appropriate.

In connection with verbs of opinion the to-infinitive is mostly the linking verb to be, which is of so little importance that it is often dropped.

Then you get a shortened verb construction: I think the measures of the government appropriate.

I see the whole part after to think as the object, a complex object consisting of an accusative and a to-infinitive.
But there are other views about these structures as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this grammatically similar to the construction *deem it necessary*?

Yes, it is. See my answer in [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158644/see-it-important-or-see-it-as-important/158689#158689)

Comment: If you know the answer, why do you direct the OP elsewhere? Why not copy and paste that short answer here? Leave the link by all means.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - Basically, because I'd have to paste the question as well. A link seemed simpler.